# Usage of LocalKeyEncryptionKeyAsyncClient

Tags: java, azure, azure-storage

I am trying to upload blob to azure blob storage, but I'd like to have client side encryption with keys stored on my side(not on Azure KeyVault). I'd like to use newest Java SDK - v12.
I have found that for client side encryption I should use EncryptedBlobClient class, which is instanced through EncryptedBlobClientBuilder.
EncryptedBlobClientBuilder requires AsyncKeyEncryptionKey to be set, and I'd like to use keys stored on my side - is LocalKeyEncryptionKeyAsyncClient used for these needs? I can not find much about this class.
Thank you

Comment: Do you mean that encrypt blob and upload with keys stored on your local, not on keyVault?

Comment: @PamelaPeng yes, that's exactly what I mean. I can not find much about that kins of encryption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-encrypt-decrypt-blobs-key-vault#encrypt-blob-and-upload) uses `ResolveKeyAsync` method to return an RsaKey. If you don't want to store the Key into KeyVault then it's no need to use this, you could use the key as you like.

```
RsaKey rsa = new RsaKey("your private Key");

// Create the encryption policy to be used for upload and download.
BlobEncryptionPolicy policy = new BlobEncryptionPolicy(rsa, null);

// Set the encryption policy on the request options.
BlobRequestOptions options = new BlobRequestOptions();
options.setEncryptionPolicy(policy);

// Upload the encrypted contents to the blob.
blob.upload(stream, size, null, options, null);
```

For more details, see the similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43930736/13308381).

---

**Update:**

There is an [answer](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/6569#issuecomment-614344184) of the similar issue.

```
JsonWebKey localKey = JsonWebKey.fromAes(new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKeyBytes, "AES"), Arrays.asList(KeyOperation.WRAP_KEY, KeyOperation.UNWRAP_KEY)).setId("my-id");

AsyncKeyEncryptionKey akek = new LocalKeyEncryptionKeyClientBuilder().buildAsyncKeyEncryptionKey(localKey).block();

EncryptedBlobClient encryptedBlobClient = new EncryptedBlobClientBuilder()
    .endpoint(serviceClient.getAccountUrl())
    .sasToken("<SAS token>")
    .containerName(containerName)
    .blobName(blobName)
    .key(akek, KeyWrapAlgorithm.A256KW.toString())
    .buildEncryptedBlobClient();

encryptedBlobClient.uploadFromFile(filepath);
```

Comment: Code you showed here is tied to older version of SDK, I need newest one - SDK12. I am not able to find what's similar to BlobEncryptionPolicy

Comment: @dolphin [`BlobEncryptionPolicy`](http://azure.github.io/ref-docs/java/com/microsoft/azure/storage/blob/BlobEncryptionPolicy.html) is based on com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob. First you need to add the [dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.azure/azure-storage-blob/12.0.0).

Comment: I already have that dependency, but BlobEncryptionPolicy doesn't seem to be part of that package. 
BlobEncryptionPolicy belongs to older version of com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob. To have BlobEncryptionPolicy you should add dependency 
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-storage</artifactId>
    <version>8.6.5</version>
</dependency>
.
I am looking for something which is equivalent to BlobEncryptionPolicy in new SDK